# Creating a `regex` language for listings

Tags: listings

A coworker is currently writing a long document with a focus on regular expressions. We would like to be able to format the regular expressions as a listings language, with syntax highlighting and such.

The main difficulty arises from the fact that the elements to highlight in the code are "*special*" characters such as `? + { } ( ) ^ [ ]`.

I have tried the following definition:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{regex}{
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  keywords={},
  otherkeywords={^, \{, \}, ?, +},
  alsoletter={},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=true,
  literate=%
  *{0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1
  {1}{{{\color{red}1}}}1
  {2}{{{\color{red}2}}}1
  {3}{{{\color{red}3}}}1
  {4}{{{\color{red}4}}}1
  {5}{{{\color{red}5}}}1
  {6}{{{\color{red}6}}}1
  {7}{{{\color{red}7}}}1
  {8}{{{\color{red}8}}}1
  {9}{{{\color{red}9}}}1
  {(}{{{\bfseries\color{blue}(}}}1
  {)}{{{\bfseries\color{blue}\)}}}1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=regex]
  ((a+b){4,5})*c? + [^ab{?]{3}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Which seems a bit hacky but close to working. I have two main questions:

1. only the opening round brackets are coloured, not the closing ones, how could I fix this? I have tried setting the brackets as keywords, no success there.
2. would it be possible to make this definition more $\LaTeX$ standard compliant/optimised?

Comment: You have `\)` should be `)`  like `(` on the line above

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the comment. This solution does not work for me either. The bracket is shown, but not in colour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I could not find an answer to this issue using `listings`, I decided to give it a go with `minted`, by creating a custom lexer for regular expressions, which seems to be the best possible solution.

The lexer is not currently available on PyPi, and is not yet perfect (but all suggestions are welcome). You can clone the repo from [here](https://gitlab.inria.fr/oirwin/regex-lexer). The installation can be done with a classic `pip install .` and then the lexer is available in both `minted` and `Pygments`.

Comment: Would you mind to share the lexer?

Comment: @egreg, done! If at any point you have suggestions for improvements, please send them through